# Python infinite series pi/4

Tags: python

I have a problem to solve, but I am having some trouble. Here is the problem:

The value of π/4 can be approximated by the infinite series: 1−1/3+1/5−1/7...

Have your program prompt the user for how many terms to use for the approximation and then display the result. Also show the user how much error is introduced by subtracting the approximated answer from Python’s math.pi value.

Example: User enters 4. Approximated value is ~.723809524. Error = ~0.06158863939745

Here is my code:

```
def proj3_6():
    print("This is a program that will approximate the value of pi / 4")
    numberOfTerms = eval(input("How many terms should be used for the    approximation? "))
    expr = math.pi / 4
    roundedExpr = round(expr, numberOfTerms)
    error = math.pi - roundedExpr
    print("The approximation is: ", roundedExpr)
    print("The error would be: ", error)
```

For some reason, it prints out the wrong values for the approximation and the error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You don't seem to be using the series `1 - 1/3 + 1/5 - ...` anywhere in your code.

Comment: How would I be able to calculate the terms based on the user input of how many terms to use for the approximation. For example, lets say a user inputs 10. How would I be able to calculate the first 10 terms of the series?

Comment: Some hints: can you write a `for` loop that print out the first `n` terms in the sequence `1`, `1/2`, `1/3`, `1/4`, ...?  How about the sequence `1`, `1/3`, `1/5`, `1/7`, ...?  Now try to produce the sequence `1`, `-1/3`, `1/5`, `-1/7`, ... (with alternating signs).  Now work out how to sum those to get your approximation.  If you post code showing how far you get with the above hints, we can probably help further from that point on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need some kind of loop in your code to iterate through each part of the series. The problem could be solved using the following approach:

```
import itertools
import math

terms = int(input("How many terms should be used for the approximation? "))
pi4 = 0.0

for numerator, denominator in zip(itertools.cycle([1.0, -1.0]), range(1, terms * 2, 2)):
    pi4 += float(numerator) / denominator

print("Approximated value is ~", pi4)
print("Error is ~", (math.pi / 4.0) - pi4)
```

Giving you the output:

```
How many terms should be used for the approximation? 4
Approximated value is ~ 0.7238095238095239
Error is ~ 0.061588639587924376
```

`range` is used to give the numbers `1 3 5 7`, and `itertools.cycle` is used to produce an alternating `1.0 -1.0` sequence. `zip` is used to combine the two for the loop.